# Return Value Relative Cell Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I need to return the value of a cell, one row down and over to the last column in the table without making that cell active. I already have VBA returning the last column. 
      This does not work.

```
WorkPercent = Cells(2, LastCol - 1).Value
```

Comment: "does not work?"  What error message are you getting?  Where's the other code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about "the cell one row below and one column to the right of a specific table", you could try:

```
Sub main()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = sheet.ListObjects("tbl")

    lastCol = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Column
    lastRow = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Row

    MsgBox sheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: As I said, I already have the last row and column worked out.

Comment: In that case, can you clarify your question?  The code I posted reads the cell one row down, one column across, from a table, without making it active; is that not what you were wanting?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the Offset property

```
WorkPercent  = Cells(2, LastCol - 1).Offset(1, 0).Value
```

Comment: For some reason or another, I cannot get this formula to land on the correct cell.  Is there a way to get the cell that the formula references to jump up, flash, and do backflips?

Comment: In so many words, I have no clue as to the cell which this formula is pointing, because it's not returning any value, and it should.

Comment: I figured out why your formula doesn't work.  The cell you are starting is on absolute row 2.  The first iteration of my whole routine starts on row 7 and advances by 2 with every other iteration. and I need it to advance 2 rows.   Here's the crude way of working it.  PercentCount = PercentCount + 2
WorkPercent = Cells(5 + PercentCount, LastCol).Offset(1, 0).Value